# Bug when posting a form from within a frameset in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, frames

The scenario is as follows.

We have 2 servers; one 'old' running old webshop (asp, on shared host) and one new running new webshop and new website (php, on our own box).

Lets say old server responds to dom1.com and new server responds to dom2.com.

Now we want the new shop to be shown when we go to dom1.com, thus we have made a frameset in the index.html that loads dom2.com website. This is a great solution, because we have no control of the DNS on the shared host - which handles DNS for dom1.com.

Heres the joker. On the main site on the new webshop we have a form. When viewing the website through the frame - dom1.com - the form don't work. When viewing directly on dom2.com the form works correct! And now to the even stranger part, this is not a problem on FireFox, Safari, Chrome (mac or windows). This problem only occur on IE8 - haven't tested 7/6.

And also, trying to use the form on dom2.com - which is a succes. And THEN trying through dom1.com - then it works!

The form is a one-field form, only input is a 8-letter code, if correct code it shows photos connected to the code.

Any guess on this one?

Comment: If i add dom2.com to "Websites i trust" then it works :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is surely due to MS' same-origin policy in InternetExplorer..

Redirected the website to dom2.com from dom1.com/index.asp